# React lazy loading leads to error while in production

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, tabs, lazy-loading

Our project has a dynamic Tab bar, uses redux and custom hooks to manage to add and remove and selection changed. We provide the custom hooks for all routers and actions to add a new tab and display the components relate to it. This tab bar works well with lazy loading in development but always gets 'TypeError: can't resolve read-only property _status of #Object' in production (node sripts/build.js or react-scripts build) even only using `React.lazy(() => import)`. Below are the codes and component stack:

TabHooks:

```
type AddType = (tabName: string, keepComponent: JSX.Element) => void;

export const useNewAliveTab = (): AddType => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const aliveRef = useRef<KeepAlive>();

  return (tabName: string, keepComponent: JSX.Element) => {
    const now = Date.now().toString();
    const keepAliveElement = (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader type="converging-spinner" size="large" />}>
        <KeepAlive aliveRef={aliveRef} name={now} key={now}>
          <ErrorBoundary>{ keepComponent }</ErrorBoundary>
        </KeepAlive>
      </Suspense>
    );

    dispatch(
      addNewTab({
        tabName: tabName,
        uuid: now,
        element: keepAliveElement,
      })
    );
  };
};

type DropType = (tabId: string) => void;

export const useDropAliveTab = (): DropType => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { dropScope } = useAliveController();

  return (tabId: string) => {
    dispatch(removeTab(tabId));
    dropScope(tabId);
  };
};

type DropCurrentType = () => void;

export const useDropCurrentTab = (): DropCurrentType => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { dropScope } = useAliveController();
  const { current } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.aliveTabs);

  return () => {
    dispatch(removeTab(current));
    dropScope(current);
  };
};
```

TabComponent:

```
const AliveTabBarComponent = (): JSX.Element => {

  const { tabAmount, tabs, current } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.aliveTabs
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const dropTab = useDropAliveTab();

  const onTabChange = (event: TabStripSelectEventArguments, newValue: string) =>
    dispatch(changeSelectedTab(newValue));

  return (
    <>
      <TabStrip selected={tabs.findIndex(item => item.id === current)} onSelect={e => onTabChange(e, tabs[e.selected].id)}>
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <TabStripTab
            key={tab.id}
            title={
              tabAmount !== 0 && (
                <GridLayout
                  gap={{ rows: 6, cols: 6 }}
                  rows={[{ height: "100%" }]}
                  cols={[{ width: "90%" }, { width: "10%" }]}>
                  <GridLayoutItem col={1} row={1}>
                    <Tooltip anchorElement="target" position="top">
                      <Typography.p textAlign="center">
                        {tab.tabName}
                      </Typography.p>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </GridLayoutItem>
                  <GridLayoutItem col={2} row={1}>
                    <Tooltip anchorElement="target" position="top">
                      <Button
                        iconClass="k-icon k-i-close"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          e.stopPropagation();
                          dropTab(tab.id);
                        }}></Button>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </GridLayoutItem>
                </GridLayout>
              )
            }>
            {tab.keepElement}
          </TabStripTab>
        ))}
      </TabStrip>
    </>
  );
};

export default AliveTabBarComponent;
```

TabReduxInitState:

```
    interface AliveTabs {
        tabs: AliveTabContentList;
        current: string;
        tabAmount: number;
    }
    
    interface AliveTabContent {
        tabName: string;
        id: string;
        keepElement: JSX.Element;
    }
    
    type AliveTabContentList = Array<AliveTabContent>;
    
    export const initialAliveTabsState: AliveTabs = {
        tabs: new Array<AliveTabContent>(),
        current: "",
        tabAmount: 0,
    };

TabReduxReducers
interface PayloadProps {
    uuid: string;
    tabName: string;
    element: JSX.Element;
}

export const aliveTabsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "aliveTabsSlice",
    initialState: initialAliveTabsState,
    reducers: {
        changeSelectedTab(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
            state.current = action.payload;
        },
        addNewTab(state, action: PayloadAction<PayloadProps>) {
            state.tabAmount++;
            state.current = action.payload.uuid;
            state.tabs.push({
                tabName: action.payload.tabName,
                id: action.payload.uuid,
                keepElement: action.payload.element,
            });
        },
        removeTab(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
            const index = state.tabs.findIndex(
                (item) => item.id === action.payload
            );
            const isCurrentTab = state.current === action.payload;
            if (index !== -1) {
                state.tabAmount--;
                state.tabs.splice(index, 1);
                if (index === 0) {
                    if (state.tabAmount > 0) {
                        if (isCurrentTab) {
                            state.current = state.tabs[index].id;
                        }
                    } else {
                        state.current = "0";
                    }
                } else if (index > state.tabAmount) {
                    if (isCurrentTab) {
                        state.current = state.tabs[state.tabAmount].id;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (isCurrentTab) {
                        state.current = state.tabs[index - 1].id;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
});

export default aliveTabsSlice.reducer;
```

And we use above like this:

```
const Layout = (): JSX.Element => {
    const newTab = useNewAliveTab();
    const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./TestComponent"));

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={e => newTab("Test Tab", <LazyComponent />)}>Click Me</Button>
            <AliveTabBarComponent />
        </>
    )
}
```

We run the codes above very well in development but always get the TypeError in production and the component stack is below:

```
"
    at Lazy
    at i (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:241027)
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:46905)
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:46905)
    at Suspense
    at ke (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:50149)
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:50398)
    at Oe (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:51153)
    at div
    at div
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:45629)
    at Suspense
    at je (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:53198)
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:53483)
    at div
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:44132)
    at J (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:44736)
    at t (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.cb249e87.js:2:56400)"
```

No idea how to solve. We use this tab to keep alive the components using react-activation, I have tried this is not its problem. And also not the UI framework problem for we have the same issues on Material-UI V4 and Kendo-react.

Comment: are you serving this application at the root route or smth like `domain.com/non-react-prefix`? if the second option then I can assume that the root cause in the `publicPath` (I will provide the ultimate answer)

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič I host in the localhost:3000 using serve but domain.com on IIS is the same

Comment: @KAMyAw I have the same problem - and I am using the lazy load in a similar way - passing the component to be lazy loaded into another component as a property. I am considering rewriting this to simplify it :( Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @Korimako Sadly, I didn't find a solution. Our project change back to react-router.

Comment: @KAMyAw it may be too late for you at this stage - and may not work, but I did find a way through the problem that I was having and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a similar situation.

I was passing a jsx object with a lazy load element in it into a variable that got used in a dialog component separate from the component I was setting the variable in. A pattern a little like this:

```
setDialogBody(<><Suspense><LazyLoadedComponent/></Suspense></>);
```

It was also throwing an error around the 'read-only property _status of #Object' in production.

My solution was to make a new component that contained the LazyLoadComonent and the LazyLoadComponent import logic - I called it a wrapper.

```
import React, {Suspense} from "react";

const LazyLoadComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./LazyLoadComponent'));

export default function LazyLoadComponentWrapper () {
    return <Suspense><LazyLoadComponent/></Suspense>
}
```

Then I passed that wrapper component into the same pattern:

```
setDialogBody(<LazyLoadedComponent/>);
```

I think this simplified it for the minimize code - or shifted the lazyload logic in the same place as where the lazy load was actually taking place in a way that resolved some complication. Anyway, it worked for me.

Perhaps it will work for you too if you try the same approach and use a wrapper component here:

```
<Button onClick={e => newTab("Test Tab", <LazyComponentWrapper />)}>Click Me</Button>
```